# Run some code when model field’s value changes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class EditableField(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(FieldTemplate)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = FSMField(default='new', protected=True)
```

Using [Django FSM](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm) I have the following state machine:

```
[*] --> new

new --> edited
new --> approved

edited --> approved
edited --> rejected

rejected --> edited

approved --> closed

closed --> [*]
```

(You can visualize it with [PlantUML](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/))

In case you don’t know FSM, each transition is done by calling an annotated model method, like this:

```
@transition(field='state',
            source=['new', 'edited'],
            target='approved')
def approve(self):
    # I can make some side effects here, or just pass, the transition will
    # be done either way, unless an exception is raised
    pass
```

Now I want to get to the `edited` state by simply setting the `value` field of my model. Is there a way to do this without using `.save()`, like a signal or something? I took a look at the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/), but cannot find anything usable. I’m using Django 1.7, but willing to upgrade to 1.8 if needed.

**Edit**: the main problem here is that I have this model attached to another one via a `ManyToManyField`, and that other model is rendered with a form. Users go to the site, fill in the `EditableField` values. `form.save()` then saves the main model (and through that, the `EditableField` records, too).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create update_or_create method can be used as one liner code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method for your model and intercept the setting of the `value` attribute:

```
class EditableField(models.Model):    
    ...    
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'value':
            print u'The "value" attr is set to {}'.format(value)
        super(EditableField, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it raises `KeyError: 'state'`. Also, because of `protected=True` I cannot directly modify the `state` field’s value (and I don’t really want to, as my annotations would be compromised this way).

Answer (score 0):

In fact Django has signals available as you said, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/, I dont know if that's what you are looking for. They work in a similar way as database triggers.

You can also override the save() method but you already said you dont want that solution.

Comment: None of Django's signals are applicable to the poster's question.

Comment: Yes they are applicable

Comment: To do what the OP is asking about, you either have to override `__setattr__` as noted in another answer or wrap access to the field in a property. If you know of a way to use signals for this, I know I'd be interested in seeing the specifics of how you'd accomplish that.